# How do I switch characters?

Tags: marvel-avengers-battle-for-earth

I just downloaded the [Marvel Avengers: Battle for Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Avengers:_Battle_for_Earth) demo on the 360 for my kids, and we can't figure out how to switch from Hulk to Thor. The boys flail about and switch them randomly, but we haven't figured out how to do it on purpose. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Stand up straight with your right arm down to your side and lift your left are straight in the air.